# How does Html.Raw MVC helper work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-encode

I use the Html.Raw to print a raw html content, for example when I send some thing like `ViewBag.div = "<div> Hello </div>";` from the controller to the view side it does not print a raw html content unless I use the `Html.Raw` method but if I have an encoded content, like content encoded using jquery and inserted into the database and I want to print it as a raw html content the `Html.Raw` method does not work and I have to use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(EncodedContent)` before I use `Html.Raw` so please could anyone explain why it acts in this way and what is the proper situation to use `Html.Raw` method? or in another way, why `Html.Raw` does not work when it receives html entities as a parameter instead of html tags?.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Because encoded characters are HTML, and the Raw version of that string is the encoded one.**

---

Html.Raw renders what it is given without doing any html encoding, so with `ViewBag.div = "<div> Hello </div>";`:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.div);
```

Renders

```
<div> Hello </div>
```

However, when you have encoded characters in there, such as `ViewBag.Something = "&gt;";` the raw version of that is `&gt;`. To get back to actual html you need to `Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(EncodedContent));` as you've said.

If Html.Raw did do the decoding then it would be confusing, and we would need something that didn't do it. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`Html.Raw` Method asks the Razor Engine ***to not encode the special chars***.

The Razor Engine encodes the special chars because it considers that you want to show them in the state you sent to it. As a result, it encodes the special chars, and the browser decodes them again to show you the characters as you sent them to the Razor Engine.

But if you use the `Html.Raw` **you are telling the Razor Engine to not encode the special chars of your content** and render the content you get as-is from, for example, your database. So, if you want to show the decoded content, you have to decode it using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` and then directly render the html tags by using `Html.Raw`.

### Example

If you have this content in your database

```
&lt;h1&gt;dklxf;&lt;span style="font-style: italic;"&gt;kldk;dlk&lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;dxl'f;dlxd'fdlf;ldk;dlkf&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
```

...if render it without using `HTML.Raw` the Razor Engine will encode the special chars in that content to be printed in the browser as-is, but if you use `HTML.Raw` it renders it to the HTML content of the page source directly. (Run the snippet)

```html
&lt;h1&gt;dklxf;&lt;span style="font-style: italic;"&gt;kldk;dlk&lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;dxl'f;dlxd'fdlf;ldk;dlkf&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
```

But if you use `Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(EncodedContent))` then your page will render the content as HTML tags. (Run the snippet)

```html
<h1>dklxf;<span style="font-style: italic;">kldk;dlk<span style="font-weight: bold;">dxl'f;dlxd'fdlf;ldk;dlkf</span></span></h1>
```