# How can I render a formated resource string stored in a Model variable as HTML in an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have resource string:

```
WelcomeText | "Hello, welcome to <a href="{0}" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>!"
```

And a web.config variable:

```
<add key="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
```

And I format them together in a Model variable:

```
return new View("Welcome", new WelcomeViewModel
{
    WelcomeText = string.Format(Resources.Resources.WelcomeText,
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WelcomeText"];
});
```

And I display the variable in a view like this:

```
<div>@Model.WelcomeText</div>
```

My problem is now that when this text is displayed in my browser, it will output this, literally:

```
Hello, welcome to <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>!
```

I can't figure out an easy way to solve this, but my knowledge of ASP.NET MVC is limited. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `@Html.Raw(Model.WelcomeText)`

Comment: What you need is `@Html.Raw`. Check this [answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105587/how-does-html-raw-mvc-helper-work)