# Error with pushing C# variables to JavaScript

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I would like to see my controller's variables in the `window` JavaScript object. I mean, globally, for particular View. For this, I have the following code in the controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        ViewBag.AdvertiserOptions = await _advertiserRepository.Advertisers.ToListAsync();
        ViewBag.CategorieOptions = await _categoryRepository.Categories.ToListAsync();

        return View();
    }
```

And on the view I have the following (to catch variables):

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        window.ManuallySending.advertiser_options = 
            JSON.parse(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.AdvertiserOptions));

        window.ManuallySending.category_options = 
                    JSON.parse(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.CategorieOptions));

    </script>
}
```

It gives me the following error:

[image]

And in the JS console in my browser:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

I'm using `newtonsoft json` library. Here is a [link on the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

So, why it is happening? How to convert this `&quot;` to ordinary `"` for my case?

#### Update

I have tried this:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        window.ManuallySending.advertiser_options = 
            JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.AdvertiserOptions)));

        window.ManuallySending.category_options = 
                    JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.CategorieOptions)));

    </script>
}
```

but it gives me new error:

> VM191:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Create:127

[image]

Comment: Does this help you in any way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105587/how-does-html-raw-mvc-helper-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@Html.Raw()`
your code should be like this

```
JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.AdvertiserOptions)));
```

Update : 
for not to having syntax error in javascript you should add a single quotation like the following

```
JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.AdvertiserOptions))');
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost works. But it gives me new one error. I have updated my question.

Comment: add single quotation like the following
JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.AdvertiserOptions))');
I'll edit my ansower

Comment: It gives me new error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

Comment: sorry you should use single quotation instead of double quotation  like this 
JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.AdvertiserOptions))');

Comment: Yes, I understand. But it has new parsing errors. Maybe you know prepared package for this? It's pretty common task. It's surprise for me that I can't find something for this in NuGet.

Comment: Maybe the reason of new error (that sounds like `VM28:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 213`) is slashes? I have in the model json field. And in the result it contains slashes.

Comment: C# or json result?

Comment: the javascript json object  please

Comment: Check this, it should solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344334/4749790