# Html.raw(), doesn't compile the code returned from jQuery

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to have multi-coloured **textarea** on my page.
So basically I am planing have one **textarea** input and one `<p>` object. When user type in **textarea**, the `<p>` will be updated with **jQuery**, as soon as user type any letters in textarea.

**Similar to Stackoverflow.**

When the user finishes typing, he will select a text from the **textarea** and click the red or blue button.
The system will read the selected text, find the index of starting text and append

```
 <span> style='color:red;'>
```

at the end of the text add

```
 </span>
```

> To be honest, I am not sure this is the best way to do it. I have seen
>   lots of RichText editor but they don't have any save button.

Anyway. 
So far what I did:

```
<div class="row">
<a href="#" name="BtnRed" id="BtnRed" class="btn btn-danger">Red</a>
<a href="#" name="BtnBlue" id="BtnBlue" class="btn btn-primary">Blue</a>

<form asp-action="Save" method="post">
    <textarea rows="10" style="width:100%" id="DetailText" name="DetailText">
        This email and any files whom this email is addressed. &lt;span&gt; style='color:red;'>This suppose to be red&lt;/span&gt;  
        Any unauthorised use, retention, distribution, copying or disclosure is strictly prohibited.
        If you have received this email in error)
    </textarea>
</form>
<hr />
@Html.Raw("<p id='viewText'></ p >");
```

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#viewText").text($("#DetailText").val());
    $("#DetailText").on('input',function () {
        $("#viewText").text(   $("#DetailText").val());
    });        
});
```

**ISSUE** Html.Raw() doesn't complie the text and shows **HTML** code instead. style='color:red;'>This suppose to be red
[image]

Comment: `Html.Raw` doesn't compile anything. It emits whatever you pass to it without escaping it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Html.Raw MVC helper work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105587/how-does-html-raw-mvc-helper-work)

Comment: Executing jQuery and emiting the resulting HTML is *NOT* trivial. It's not available out-of-the-box either. . Stackoverflow doesn't work that way anyway - it parses the Markdown text posted by users and renders it as HTML using a Markdown parser.