# ASP.NET Converting & to &amp. I need plain text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I've looked around for a while for an answer but no one has one and everyone keeps saying it's how it's supposed to work.
I need to render an & (ampersand) as plain javascript code. Not as a string.

```
if (@(Model.Month == null ? "now.getMonth() == tooltipItems[0].index" : "now.getMonth() == tooltipItems[0].index && now.getDay() == tooltipItems[0].index") && now.getFullYear() == $('#DistinctYears').val()) {
   //
} else {
   //
}
```

I need this section:

```
"now.getMonth() == tooltipItems[0].index && now.getDay() == tooltipItems[0].index"
```

To render as plain javascript code but when it renders, the ampersands automatically get converted to `&amp;&amp;`
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Html.Raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105587/how-does-html-raw-mvc-helper-work)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Html.Raw("&&") and Html.Raw("&amp;&amp;"). Neither of which, work

Comment: Did you try putting the Html.Raw around the entire ternary expression statement? @Html.Raw(Model.Month...).  Not just the &&

Comment: @BryanLewis YES, This is it thank you so much.

Comment: @BryanLewis.. Please add like an answer and let OP accept it. I liked your answer and appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the entire ternary expression with Html.Raw():

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Month == null ? "now.getMonth() == tooltipItems[0].index" : "now.getMonth() == " + (Model.Month - 1) + " && now.getDate() == (tooltipItems[0].index + 1)")
```