# Asp.net Mvc and Boostrap 4 Pagination - Show active current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

The code is doing the pagination correctly, however, I am unable to use the boostrap class that shows the active page

```
<div class="page-nation">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-large">
            <li>
                @{
                    if (ViewBag.PageNumber> 1)
                    {

                        <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Boats", new { search= ViewBag.searchData, pageNumber= ViewBag.PageNumber- 1 })">«</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a class="page-link disabled">«</a>

                    }
                }
            </li>
            @{
                var currentPage= ViewBag.PageNumber;
                for (var i = 1; i <= ViewBag.totalCount; i++)
                {
                    <li @(currentPage== i ? "class= page-item active" : "")>
                        <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Boats", new {search= ViewBag.searchData, pageNumber= i})">@i</a>
                    </li>
                }
            }

            <li>

                @if (ViewBag.PageNumber< ViewBag.totalCount)
                {
                    <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Boats", new { search= ViewBag.searchData, pageNumber= ViewBag.PageNumber+ 1 })">»</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a class="page-link disabled">»</a>
                }

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

The part that should show the active item is this, but for some reason, this class is not working

```
<li @(currentPage== i ? "class= page-item active" : "")>
```

HTML output:

As can be seen in HTML, the class is called, but it doesn't pass anything to it...

```
<div class="page-nation">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-large">
        <li>
           <a class="page-link" href="/Barcos?numeroPagina=1">«</a>
        </li>
           <li>
               <a class="page-link" href="/Boats?pageNumber=1">1</a>
           </li>
           <li class="page-item" active="">
               <a class="page-link" href="/Boats?pageNumber=2">2</a>
           </li>
        <li>
               <a class="page-link disabled">»</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the outputed HTML?

Comment: @RafaelDuarte edited my post with the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding quotes to the `class` property value, adding quotes will make your HTML render properly:

`<li @Html.Raw(currentPage== i ? "class=\"page-item active\"" : "")>`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, it is not showing yet, but now the html code of the active page looks like this:          <li class="page-item" active&quot;="">
                        <a class="page-link" href="/Boats?PageNumber=2">2</a>
                    </li>

Comment: Thx man, works great, Could you tell me why it only works using this html helper markup?

Comment: No problem, I think this answer explains it quite well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35106148/7586354